# When adding a solution to TFS why does it show other files from other solutions?

Tags: tfs

I wanted to add a new solution to TFS. After I've done so, when I show files to be archived, it shows files from other solutions and there's no button to deselect all of them, I have to deselect one by one!

How to prevent this ?

Answer (score 2):

In `Pending Changes` -tool, click on `Source Files`-subview and then on `Filter by Solutions` -button (left from Workspace -label, has "solution" icon).

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2008 you can use the Change to folder view button under the Pending Changes tab. It is beside the hide/show comments button. It groups pending checkins by solution and project. The default view is flat view.